# Rails form is not getting rendered from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a simple todo list application where I have this below code in my todos/new template

```
todos/new.html.erb

<div class="new-task">
    <%= form_tag {controller: "todos", action: "new"} , method: "post", class: "form-group" do %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <%= text_field_tag "todos[task]", "", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <%= submit_tag "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When I am trying to render this view from another controller's view using

```
<%= render template: 'todos/new' %>
```

I am getting a nasty error with below stack trace.

```
SyntaxError in ToolsController#index

app/views/todos/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
app/views/todos/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
app/views/todos/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
app/views/todos/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
app/views/todos/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
app/views/todos/new.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
app/views/tools/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_tools_index_html_erb__1039417368_95034624'
```

Please help in resolving this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<div class="new-task>` missing quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But that's got nothing to do with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
>
> The form_tag helper accepts 2 arguments: the path for the action and
>   an options hash. This hash specifies the method of form submission and
>   HTML options such as the form element's class

In your case you need to wrap the controller and action between curly braces, and the rest of options within parenthesis, like:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: 'todos', action: 'new'}, class: 'form-group') do |form| %>
  ...
```

This way Rails will turn the hash into a valid URL.

Same could be achieved by passing the URI corresponding to both, controller and action, like:

```
<%= form_tag('/todos', class: 'form-group') do |form| %>
  ...
```

Note if you leave a white space between the form_tag and the parenthesis you will have a `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL append= form_tag` error and the default method for the form_tag helper is POST, so you don't need to specify it in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually trying to pass a hash to the form_tag. Your way renders the form but the path to the action in the generated html gets messed up.

Comment: Try just passing the uri and specifying the method instead passing the controller and action `<%= form_tag '/todos', method: :post, class: "form-group" do |form| %>`